# Why is the NVIDIA control panel not showing display or video option (GTX 690, Windows 7 SP1 x64)?

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-geforce, displaylink

My NVIDIA control panel does not show display and video options:

[image]

It should have display and video options, as below:

[image]

Is that because I'm also using a [DisplayLink driver](http://www.displaylink.com/support/downloads.php)?

Answer (score -1):

NVidia Control Panel ->3D settings ->Manage 3D settings ,tab Global settings , Preferred graphics processor :select High-performance NVidia processor.
Then, open the Intel UHD Graphics Control Panel, go to display and set scaling to scale full screen and you are good to go.
Besides, some methods can be tried:

1. Choose the Default Graphics Processor in BIOS
2. Disable the Onboard Graphics Card in Device Manager
3. Restart the NVIDIA Control Panel Process

Comment: -1 from me. You can see on the screenshot that there's no _"3D settings"_ item in the left pane. Also GTX 690 is not a mobile GPU, so it's not a laptop.